# Splitting Bison grammars into smaller grammar files

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc

I have a Bison grammar file that's 700 lines long and growing; I've tried to divide it up as well as I can but as I add more complexity to my language it gets harder and harder to manage and organize all of the rules. I tried searching for some way to do the bison-equivalent of `#include` or the like, so that I could at least textually split it up, but came up dry. Is there a way for me to split my grammar into smaller modules without resorting to makefile hacks or the like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bison has no facility analogous to C's `#include`.

Adding a preprocessor step to your bison recipe is not a "makefile hack", imho, but rather an expected use case for `make`.

It's a bit tricky to use `cpp` on bison files because they tend to use `#define` directives in their prologues, but there are other preprocessors. For a simple case, you can just use `cat`.

Comment: I was hoping to keep my interactive compilation feedback working in vim, but so it goes. `cat` it is. Thanks!

Comment: Speaking of Vim, Vim's folding understands `.y` files. You can collapse your view of the grammar file so the rules appear as folds.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of splitting up the grammar itself, you can condense it down to mostly a sequence of one-liners by having the rule bodies call functions:

```
 foo : ID bar '{' whatever_list '}' { $$ = ast_node_foo($1, $2, $4); }
     ;
```

The details of the syntax-directed translation scheme rest in these functions, which can be split into modules.

Comment: Is there a software in production that primarily uses this?

Comment: @user1424739 I suspect, lots. E.g.the [old Yacc C++ parser](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/branches/gcc-3_3-branch/gcc/cp/parse.y?revision=159936&view=markup)  that was used by GCC  mostly has node-constructing actions. The new parser is a hand-written recursive-descent job, but still works by building a tree.

Comment: Any very simple one that primarily for showing how to best manage grammar rules but more simpler that GCC?

Answer (score 0):

[btyacc](https://github.com/ChrisDodd/btyacc) is a yacc variant that supports `%include` to read from multiple files

```
%include bar.y   /* inserts the contents of bar.y at this point */
```

While btyacc supports all of POSIX yacc, it only supports a couple of bison extensions, however.

Comment: Interesting. Is there any documentation around the differences between btyacc and bison? I'd like to stick with something that's got packages for basically every distribution, I'm not sure that support for `%include` is enough to get me to jump ship.